# Azure DevOps deploy dotnet core package without IIS to deployment group

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to figure out how to use deployment groups.

I have an artifact that contains an asp.net core website which uses "gRPC". grpc makes the package incompatible with IIS, but runs fine with `dotnet ABC.dll`. So thats what I try to do. Now when creating a release pipeline, only the IIS Stages have a description for the "Deployment group". All the others don't.

Basically I want to download my artifact to the servers in the deployment group, unpack the zip and execute `dotnet run` inside the folder.

Are there any other release stages compatible with deployment groups? Or should I try to use docker to run the artifact on the on-premise servers?

Update: The answer from Shayki works, i marked his post as answer. Anway, for anyone else as blind as me: after creating a task, you have the default "agent job". Delete that, and add a "deployment group job" with the 3 dots on the "deployment process" card instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any task to a deployment group job, not only the IIS Stages. just add in the release a new Deployment group job and add there your tasks (unzip and `dotnet run`):

[image]

Because it's a Deployment group job the job will download the artifacts to each server that exist in the group and will invoke the tasks.